# How to select netcat-traditional in Ubuntu in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, netcat

I want to use netcat-traditional in Ubuntu but configure this in a Dockerfile, so obviously I cannot use the helpful command prompt triggered when running `sudo update-alternatives --config nc`

How do I select the correct option automatically without being prompted?

[These instructions explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193748/61072) what I want to do but assume access to a command prompt.

Comment: Check the `--set` option in [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the default netcat without being prompted at the command line, type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set nc /bin/nc.traditional
```

From [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html):

> ```
> --set name path
> ```
>
> Set the program path as alternative for name. This is
>   equivalent to `--config` but is non-interactive and thus
>   scriptable.